# Should "Scan Disk" be using more than 10G of RAM in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, bad-sectors

I have an USB external 1TB drive connected to my PC which is running Windows 7. I am doing an "erro-checking" on it, and I selected the "Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors". After running for a few minutes I notices that the process is using up 10G of RAM on my 12G system. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that was present in the RTM build but Microsoft didn't see it.

They seem to believe the cause was out of date/incompatible chipset drivers with Windows 7.  The recommendation was to update your chipset drivers.

[Microsoft gets personal on Windows 7 "show stopper" bug](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/08/05/windows_7_show_stopper_bug/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it's because it's available. File system consistency checking usually isn't cheap with modern file systems and a traditional space/speed trade-off may apply here.